# Grafana Panel to send data to InfluxDB

Tags: grafana, influxdb, flux

I would like to ask a question regarding flux and Grafana.
Is there a panel in Grafana that allows someone to write data to InfluxDB using Flux or InfluxQL, if there is please point me to the documentation.

I have tried using the Test panel but I can't send data to influxdb

Comment: What do you mean? Grafana is a tool for visualization data (for example from influxdb), and it usually only reads data from data source.